# Template type member variables in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to change the type of a membervariable, based on whats written within my template.

For example `A<64, 64>` should make my member to int_128
Sadly, I have no idea how to work with template types, and every tutorial I find only helps with template functions.

my class looks like

```
template<int x, int y>
class A{

    private:
    TYPETOBEGENERIC m_variable
}
```

Is there a way do it in the constructor like

```
if( x+y <= 64){ TYPETOBEGENERIC = int_64 }
    else{TYPETOBEGENERIC = int_128}
```

I don't want to add the specific type within the template<>. The structure A<64, 64> should be untouched.

Comment: C++ doesn't have generics, it has templates, and they aren't the same thing, nor even similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
constexpr bool lessThan64(int a,int b) {
    return (a+b) < 64;
} 
template<int x, int y>
class A{
    using type = typename std::conditional<lessThan64(x,y),int_64,int_128>::type;
    private:
    type m_variable;
}
```

Using constexpr functions to get compile time metaprogramming we can evaluate those values at compile time and then use std::conditional to chose between the two types.

Edit:
For more than two types you can use variadic templates or explicit specialization.

```
template<unsigned int I,typename... Sizes>
struct select;

template<unsigned int I,typename T,typename... Sizes>
struct select<I,T,Sizes...>:select<N-1,Cases...>
{
}    

template<unsigned int I,typename T,typename... Sizes>
struct select<O,T,Sizes...>
{
    using type =T
}

You would obviously need a constexpr function to differentiate between the types.
```

Comment: You're welcome man clearcase is wasting my time today.I'm happy to help

Comment: Just a last question, if I would like to put in a third variable to use here, lets just say an int_32 as example, how would I need to alter this. std:conditional seems to work only with true/false states.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre-processor commands to parametrize the number of bits after the `int_` that but that's bad programming.

```
#define TYPE(bits) int_##bits
```

Now to declare a 32 bits integer (assuming that such a type exists) you write `TYPE(32) my_var;`. There probably are better ways to do whatever you are trying to do.